# GitHub action unable to upload jar file in github pckage

Tags: maven, github-actions, cicd, github-package-registry, github-packages

I am using GitHub action to deploy a BW6 applications also store the artifact in github package. below is my dev.yaml file

```
name: Tibco Workflow

on:
  

 pull_request:
  branches: [ dev ]
 release:
    types: [created]
    

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: [self-hosted,tibco,esb,bw6]
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3


      - name: Set up JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
         java-version: 11.0.16+8
         distribution: 'adopt'
         cache: maven

          
      - name: Clean target folder 
        run: |
            mvn -B -f src/{appname}/pom.xml clean 
            
      - name: Building jar file
        run: |
            mvn install -f C:\actions-runner\_work\{appname}\{appname}\src\{appname}\pom.xml
            
      - name: Publish to GitHub Packages Apache Maven
        run: mvn package -s C:\Users\{user}\.m2\settings.xml
        env:
         GITHUB_TOKEN: {GitHub Token}
```

But i am getting error :

3s

```
Run mvn package -s C:\Users\{user}\.m2\settings.xml
  mvn package -s C:\Users\{user}\.m2\settings.xml
  shell: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
  env:
    JAVA_HOME: C:\actions-runner\_work\_tool\Java_Adopt_jdk\11.0.16-8\x64
    JAVA_HOME_11_X64: C:\actions-runner\_work\_tool\Java_Adopt_jdk\11.0.16-8\x64
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ***
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Micro Focus\UFT One\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar"
Error:  Error executing Maven.
Error:  The specified user settings file does not exist: C:\Users\{user}\.m2\settings.xml
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

But the settings.xml file is under same locations which i mentioned in command line , basically the problem showing in "upload package" stage , mvn clean and mvn install command are working but mvn deploy to uplaod .jar file in github package registry is not working

Comment: Is this file path `C:\Users\{user}\.m2\settings.xml` present in your runners? Which runner is causing this failure?

Comment: @Azeem, yes this file path exist in my github runner ( windows server )